# NullException XML Parsing

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm having a problem with parsing XML in C#, my XML file looks like this:

```
<xml>
    <category>books</category>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>lemony</title>
    <sub>
        <title>lemonyauthor</title>
    </sub>
</xml>
<xml>
    <category>comics</category>
    <id>2</id>
    <sub>
        <title>okauthor</title>
    </sub>
</xml>
```

As you can see sometimes the title in "XML" is returned, sometimes not.

My code in C# to parse this looks like:

```
string _Title;

foreach (XElement str in xmlDoc.Descendants("xml"))
{
    _Title = "";

        if (str.Element("title").Value != null)
            _Title = str.Element("title").Value;

        foreach (XElement cha in str.Descendants("sub"))
        {
            if (_Title.Length < 1 && cha.Element("Title").Value != null)
                    _Title = cha.Element("title").Value;
        }
}
```

How do I keep the line `if (str.Element("category").Value != null)` from returning a `NullException`?

Is using `try` & `catch` the only way?

Comment: Check `str.Element("title")!=null` not `str.Element("title").Value!=null`

Comment: Thank you guys! I had forgot about the .Value part being added to my line would automatically believe it's assigned!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are expecting `str.Element("title")` (which is the most likely cause of of the exception) to be null (no matter how occasionally) then you should have a test for that:

```
if (str.Element("title") != null)
{
    // your existing code.
}
```

If you are not expecting it to be null and it truly is an exceptional circumstance then having a try catch is the only other way to stop the method crashing.

Comment: Thank you! I had forgot about the .Value part being on there.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
if (str.Element("title").Value != null)
    _Title = str.Element("title").Value;
```

to this:

```
var titleElement = str.Element("title");
if (titleElement != null)
    _Title = titleElement.Value;
```